# How to remove the last child of element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var rightSide=document.getElementById("rightSide");
var leftsidecopy = leftSide.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("leftsidecopy").removeChild();
document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(leftsidecopy);
```

I have a original copy of data in leftside.I make a copy of leftside .I remove the lastchild of leftside and initialise to rightside.This code doesnt work!

Comment: Can you please post the related HTML.

Comment: you aren't passing any node to `removeChild()` to remove

Comment: It is not clear what result you are trying to achieve.  What is `document.getElementById("leftsidecopy").removeChild()` supposed to to?  First off, you show no element with an `id="leftsidecopy"` and secondly, you pass no DOM element to `removeChild()`.  So, it appears that statement will probably just trigger an error.

Comment: @VivekAnand `leftsidecopy` element is acting as the parent , you need to specify which child to remove in `removeChild()`

Comment: removeChild(document.getElementById(leftSidecopy).lastchild); will this be right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of thing. I try on ol if you need on other tag you can try.

```
<ol id="myTestList">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
    <li>List item 6</li>
    <li>List item 7</li>
</ol>

 $('ol#myTestList li:last-child').remove();
```